# How do I show our own suggestions when we edit a textfield?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I have a textfield and an array which contains a set of words. When we edit a textfield it will show some suggestions text from the dictionary.  I want to show suggestions from my array only instead of Dictionary. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't understand the question, as Kamarshad said, please post some code.

Comment: Try this open-source control [a link](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/autocompletiontableview)

Comment: @Kamarshad :NSArray *myarray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ant",@"all",@"bat",@"ball", nil];   if I entered the letter 'a' in my text field there should be a pop up which contains the words 'ant' and 'all'. If I click on one of those words that word should be entered to the textfield.

Comment: it seems little search Functionality suppose user will use this textField for getting the content corresponding to the entered text.you should use the Delegate methods of UITextField .`- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` in this method you should write some search code which compare the entered text with your datasource and display that searched Result in UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UITableView as suggestion list. On Text field editing you can filter array and reload table data again.

Answer (score 0):

[AutocompletionTableView for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/autocompletiontableview) is the one you are looking for.

[WEPopover for iOS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover) also works same but looks different.